# Rails Devise Login 401 Unauthorized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

### What I am trying to do

I am trying to set up the Authentication with Devise in the **Session Controller**, **methods new** and **create**.
I am using **Rails 5** and I customized the **View** `new.html.erb`.

### What is the problem

I am not able to authenticate successfully after signing out from the Account. The problem is connected with the **sign_in_params hash**, which is passed blank to the *new method* of the **session_controller**

### Testing of the functionality

I conducted a **test of the Login**, by including a breakpoint in my **Account::SessionsController**, I noticed that the **sign_in_params** hash was blank, then the program exits with **401 Unauthorized**.

```
     8: def new
     9:   self.resource = resource_class.new(sign_in_params)
 => 10:   clean_up_passwords(resource)
    11:   yield resource if block_given?
    12:   respond_with(resource, serialize_options(resource))
    13: end

sign_in_params => {}
```

### My Code

I was able by **resetting my code** to identify the cause of my problem. It is connected to the custom Devise View that I modified in `app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb`

This is the code:

```
<form class="login-form" action="index.html">        
  <div class="login-wrap">
  <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
      <p class="login-img"><i class="icon_lock_alt"></i></p>
      <div class="field">
      </div>      
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon_profile"></i></span>
        <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, :class => "form-control", :placeholder => "Username" %>
        <!--<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" autofocus>-->
      </div>
      <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon_key_alt"></i></span>
          <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", :class => "form-control", :placeholder => "Password" %>
      </div>
      <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
      <label class="checkbox">
          <%= f.check_box :remember_me %> 
          <%= f.label :remember_me, :class => "remember_me_Label" %>
          <span class="pull-right"> <%= link_to "Forgot Password?", {}, :id => "lostPw" %></span>
      </label>
      <% end -%>      
      <%= f.submit "Login", :class => "btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" %>
      <%= link_to "Signup", new_account_registration_path, :method => :get, class: "btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block signuptext" %>
      <% end %>
  </div>
</form>
```

In the log, I have the following important informations, but no errors:

```
Started GET "/account/index.html?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=s1aA%2FNcZo1HIkF1qJOlrIAlM9rJM3y1ced8tQLiWnGsSugBVs0AYKVJR8QLa1I%2BT500sYu7H1%2BPQ2UwH3JG2ew%3D%3D&account%5Bemail%5D=test%40email.com&account%5Bpassword%5D=[FILTERED]&account%5Bremember_me%5D=0&commit=Login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-06 19:16:04 +0100 (pid:8311)
2017-02-06 19:16:04.557 [fyi] Processing by AccountController#index as HTML (pid:8311)
2017-02-06 19:16:04.557 [fyi] Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"s1aA/NcZo1HIkF1qJOlrIAlM9rJM3y1ced8tQLiWnGsSugBVs0AYKVJR8QLa1I+T500sYu7H1+PQ2UwH3JG2ew==", "account"=>{"email"=>"test@email.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Login"} (pid:8311)
2017-02-06 19:16:04.558 [fyi] Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms) (pid:8311)
```

Following is the solution of the problem
Thanks
Fabrizio Bertoglio

Comment: I don't even get why you are overriding the controller as it adds absolutely nothing. You can customize the views without overriding the controller. Additionally the `new`, `create` and `destroy` methods are completely superfluous as they only call super. What are you trying to customize, and why?

Comment: @max hello thanks, I need the controllers to do some redirecting, so that the user in some situations returns to the Homepage. Also for the `sign up` I have additional fields and I edited `configure_sign_up_params` in the `Registrations_controller`.
The problem is for sure with the `strong_params`, which are not passed as you can see above from the text case. Right now I am trying to understand why. Do you have any advice given the code I wrote? Thanks Fabrizio

Comment: @max I think you are right. For this reason I deleted the devise app and now I am configuring it from scratch, when all the functionalities will work, I will try making some changes, but with a different approach and trying to keep as much standard code as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

The problem is in the html code of `new.html.erb`, as I did not remove the html `<form>` tags from the html and this would cause problems with my `<%= form_for > <% end %>` rails tag. This is the reason why **strong_params** is empty.

The **form** was not submitting any value to the **controller**, the *problem* could have been easily discovered by debugging directly the `new.html.erb` view instead of the controller.

Was helpful having the input from Max, that suggested me to **restart all over with Devise**, so that I could understand that the problem was **connected with the form** and *not with rails strong parameters*.

This is the correct new.html.erb.

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name), html: { class: "login-form"}) do |f| %>
  <div class="login-wrap">
    <p class="login-img"><i class="icon_lock_alt"></i></p>    
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon_profile"></i></span>
      <%#= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, :class => "form-control", :placeholder => "Username" %>
      <!--<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" autofocus>-->
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon_key_alt"></i></span>
        <%#= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", :class => "form-control", :placeholder => "Password" %>
    </div>
    <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <%= f.check_box :remember_me %> 
        <%= f.label :remember_me, :class => "remember_me_Label" %>
        <span class="pull-right"> <%= link_to "Forgot Password?", {}, :id => "lostPw" %></span>
    </label>
    <% end -%>      
    <%= f.submit "Login", :class => "btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" %>
    <%= link_to "Signup", new_registration_path(resource_name), :method => :get, class: "btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block signuptext" %>

    <div class="links ">
    <%= render "devise/shared/links2" %>
    </div>

  </div>
<% end %>

<div class="text-right">
        <div class="credits">
            <!-- 
                All the links in the footer should remain intact. 
                You can delete the links only if you purchased the pro version.
                Licensing information: https://bootstrapmade.com/license/
                Purchase the pro version form: https://bootstrapmade.com/buy/?theme=NiceAdmin
            -->
            <a href="https://bootstrapmade.com/free-business-bootstrap-themes-website-templates/">Business Bootstrap Themes</a> by <a href="https://bootstrapmade.com/">BootstrapMade</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```